# Does retinal detachment happen more frequently at night?

Tags: vision, eyes

My understanding and experience is that during the night photoreceptors are less tightly coupled to the retinal pigment epithelium.  Does this make it more likely for a retinal detachment to happen at night?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of normal, healthy person, no, I don't think so. In fact, retinal detachment could happen at anytime of the day. Main causes are diseases and illness, such as AIDS, diabetic retinopathy, cancer, or trauma such as post-cataract surgery and being hit/kicked hard on the eyes.